# SignalR v2 with load balancer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am pretty new to SignalR and have been going through some tutorials as I've been tasked with upgrading our current implementation.

We've got an ASP.NET MVC application which uses SignalR (version 1.x). The application is in our F5 load-balanced cloud environment. So we have multiple sites (for different customers) using the same load balancer. To make the SignalR calls servers-side, we use the `HubConnection` from the **Microsoft.ASPNET.SignalR.Client** namespace and create a proxy like this (full example [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client)):

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");
stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>("UpdateStockPrice", stock => Console.WriteLine("Stock update for {0} new price {1}", stock.Symbol, stock.Price));
await hubConnection.Start();
```

Where `http://contoso.com/` is the current customer's site URL.

We are looking to upgrade to the latest SignalR (version 2.x) and I am wondering if it is necessary to even use the `HubConnection`. Even though the article above specifies version 2, it does mention:

> This document provides an introduction to using the Hubs API for SignalR version 2 in .NET clients, such as Windows Store (WinRT), WPF, Silverlight, and console applications.

This is a web application with a regular class library back-end for data access. Taking a look at this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc), I don't see anything about `HubConnection` (it also doesn't mention load balancing). Consider the following, from the Chat tutorial:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Then, in **Statup.cs**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

So my question is, are we using SignalR properly? If not, what considerations/modifications need to be made when running a load-balanced application which uses SignalR (v2.x)? I haven't been able to find much regarding load balancing, etc.

Or is this a job for [Groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to change anything structural. Have a look at the [signalr redis scaleout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis), or any other scaleout option. Basically you need to install an additional package and ms opentech redis to do load balancing. So the scaleout will make sure that each request is sent over a message bus, making multiple servers possible.

Comment: Just to clarify, is using Redis considered the **best practice**, but still **optional**? The reason I ask is because we aren't using that currently, but it still seems to work across our load balancers as-is. I'm curious if I remove our `HubConnection` logic and replace it with the `ChatHub` logic in my 2nd example, if I'll run into any issues.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Communicate between the load-balanced servers via a hubconnection?

Comment: Not necessarily between load balanced servers, but from load balanced servers to the client. I'm curious if the hub connection and proxy are necessary.

Comment: I'm looking into scaling out w/ sql server now: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server This seems feasible as we're already using sql server.

Comment: You use the proxy for a .net client, so why would you use a .net client on the server? In other words: no it's not nescessary. You use the hub on the server and a proxy (javascript or .net) on the client side. That has nothing to do with load balancing. You need a service bus between your servers with signalr else it won't work. So yes redis is nescessary and quite easy to set up. You could also go for sql scaleout but that doesn't perform very well. If you're on azure you can use azure service bus.

Comment: Yes it did. I am going with the SQL Server option. Thanks again!